# Cassandra: too many sstables - node goes down instantly

Tags: cassandra

- using Cassandra 2.2.8.

I'm in  situation where too many SSTables (98,000+) are created for a single table and many more for other CFs. Node keeps crashing complaining insufficient memory for jre.   I've tried increasing linux nofile limit to 200K and max_heap_size to 16G but no avail!

Looking for help to know ways as how i can reduce # of SSTables (compaction?) and keep node up so to do the maintenance.

Thanks in advance!

errors:

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2627), pid=22667, tid=139622017013504

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007efc78b83000):  JavaThread "MemtableFlushWriter:2" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=22726, stack(0x00007efc48b61000,0x00007efc48ba2000)]

Stack: [0x00007efc48b61000,0x00007efc48ba2000],  sp=0x00007efc48b9f730,  free space=249k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xab97ea]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ba
V  [libjvm.so+0x4f9dcb]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*)+0x8b
V  [libjvm.so+0x91a7c3]  os::Linux::commit_memory_impl(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x103
V  [libjvm.so+0x91ad19]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x29
V  [libjvm.so+0x91502a]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x2a

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)

Comment: Did you change compaction related settings in cassandra.yml ?

Comment: Hi there, thankyou for taking my question. No, compaction related settings are not changed; infact no changes are made in Cassandra.yaml file at all. I can see when initializing C*, SSTabes are opened which are huge in number! Leaving no room for JVM that as result shuts down with oom error. Iam not able to start the node now

Comment: Can you put all your error and warn log ?

Answer (score 1):

I would treat this as a dead node situation:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

After you finish the procedure the node will have way less sstables etc. The thing that is bothering me is how did you come into this situation. Can you provide some schema, insert, delete, ttl related info and describe the workload?

Comment: hello there- Thank you sharing your time and experience here.

Is there possibility/other way to deal such situation like I'm thinking if we can compact sstables -
move all those SStables to backup directory but keep few in SSTable's directory and than start the node. 
once node is up than compact those few SSTables; once the process completes do the same for rest of SSTables following rinse and repeat! 
Please share if that would work or you have better ideas.

I came to know developers are working to 'fix the code' though I still need to bring the node up and get out of this situation

Comment: It's also possible to do that ... you can remove the tables to a location and then add them by calling nodetool refresh every time you added something new... but you might get a lot of data not found eceptions, depending on how you configured your clients ... quorum etc. What compaction strategy are you using? (is it time windowed?)

Comment: Hi Marko.. we're using STCS - work load is write heavy

Comment: are you using TTL or you are keeping data forever?

Comment: i can see this CF is set @ default TTL, we probably need to adjust that value too.. I'm going to ask developers about that

Comment: Hey @Marko Švaljek - Thank you.
I'll follow thru the plan and will get back and share.. thank again for your help thus far.